# Show error message OF nested formgroup under AOT compilation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a formGroup  **customerForm** and **inside** this i have another formgroup **address**  and i want to show a required message in html.In JIT complier i can do this by

```
customerForm.controls.address.controls.street_address.name.valid
```

But in AOT Compiler i am getting errors in this.
Please suggest some solution in this.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Property street_address does not exist on type ‘{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `get` syntax instead. Something like this:

```
customerForm.get('address.street_address.name').valid;
```

NOTE: I could not verify this syntax without a plunker but this should be close.